# Problem Deleting Item from Sharepoint Calender list

Tags: delete

I have 2 calender list Name A and B. when i delete items from list A, it should delete item from list B. List A items get deleted successfully but list B items throws SpException. but when i again run the program, it successfully deletes the items from B too. what can be the issue?. I am using  `DisabledItemEventsScope` while deleting.

Comment: Can you post here the exception? Code snippet would be also useful.

Comment: i solved it. i was not disposing web object. thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this after listname.DeleteItemById

```
 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
 web.Dispose();
```